I can't make a turn for the tank AI
Task
Design a code that will initialize a random point on the map, after which the tank will begin smooth movement with a turn towards this point.
Implementation attempt

rotation - Global variable responsible for the angle of rotation in
radians about the y-axis from -PI to +PI.
global_position -
Global variable storing the global coordinates of the tank.
velocity - Tank movement vector, in this case it is always directed
up and simply rotated using the rotate() method.

func _find_random_point():
     var _random_point = Vector2(randf_range(0, 500), randf_range(0, 500))
     # Sets the coordinates of a random point on the map
     return _random_point

var target_position = _find_random_point() # Назначает координаты в переменную

func _rad_to_rad(rad):
    if rad > PI:
        return PI - rad
    elif rad < -PI:
        return rad - PI
    else:
        return rad

func _abs_rad(rad):
    if rad < 0:
        return PI + (PI - abs(rad))
    else:
        return rad

func _abs_rotation(rad): 
    if rad > 0 and rad < PI / 2:
        return 2*PI + rad
    else:
        return rad

func move_to_random_point(delta):
    # Finds the vector to the target and turns it into an angle in radians
    var direction = (target_position - global_position).normalized().angle()
    # Finds the distance to the target
    var distance = global_position.distance_to(target_position)
    # Code to display the point
    var a = TRUCK_TRACES.instantiate()
    a.global_position = target_position
    a.top_level = true
    add_child(a)
    a = TRUCK_TRACES.instantiate()
    a.global_position = Vector2(target_position.x, target_position.y + 10)
    a.top_level = true
    add_child(a)

    if not moving:
        moving = true
        timer_for_turn.wait_time = 0.01
        timer_for_turn.start()
    else:
        if _rad_to_rad(direction + PI / 2) < 0:
            direction = PI-0.1
                
        if time_out_for_turn == true:
            time_out_for_turn = false

        # An attempt to align the rotation angle and vector to the target. 
            if _abs_rotation(_abs_rad(rotation)) < _abs_rad(direction + PI / 2):
                rotation += rotation_speed * delta 
            elif _abs_rotation(_abs_rad(rotation)) > _abs_rad(direction + PI / 2):
                rotation -= rotation_speed * delta
            
            

    if global_position.distance_to(target_position) < 100:
        moving = false
        target_position = _find_random_point()

    velocity = -Vector2(0, max_speed)
    velocity = velocity.rotated(rotation)
    #print(velocity.angle())
    #print(rotation)
    move_and_slide()

I tried different ways to compare the rotation and angle to the target, trying to change the rotation in through the conditions of more less.
I tried to implement the rotation through the conditions of increasing and decreasing degrees of rotation relative to the target, but at the moment when the target is strictly vertical from the tank, the tank simply begins to zigzag in the direction from the target.

This is not Python

This is almost a dialect of Python, I am sure that people who know Python will understand the syntax of gdscript

It's still not Python, otherwise you could argue that any Python question should be tagged with "gdscript" as well. Anyhow, what actually is your question? What is the precise problem, what is the [mcve] that shows the issue, what are expected and actual outcomes? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].
